# Challenging Formula in excel to calculate successive remainder

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, modulo, formulas

I am trying to find a formula which will work out an allowance amount based on the time it has taken for a task to be completed.

Here is an example, in cell:

A1: I have an allowance value of 150 (which does not change)

B1: I have the time it has taken for the task to be performed

C1: I want a formula to return a value based on the criteria below

Criteria 1: 6hrs or less return 20% of the allowance    =IF(AND(B1>=0.01,B1<=5.99),A1*0.2,"")

Criteria 2: Between 6hrs and 12hrs, return 50% of the allowance
=IF(AND(B1>=6,B1<=11.99),A1*0.5,"")

Criteria 3: Between 12hrs and 24hrs, return 100% of the allowance
=IF(AND(B1>=12,B1<=23.99),A1*1,"")

Criteria 4: First 24hrs, 100% of the allowance and for each successive 12hrs add 50% of the allowance (on top of the 100% for the first 24hrs)

If possible I would like one formula to cover all those criterias into C1 cell. As you can see, I have a formula for the first three criterias but not the last one.

It would be great if someone can help. Many thanks in advance :)

Ab

Comment: The first question out of the starting gate would be whether the times to be used as criteria are actual times or integers and mixed numbers representing hours.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, there are actual times. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the FALSE condition in each IF statement with the next criteria.  If the first three criteria are FALSE it assumes you are over 24 hours and runs criteria 4.

=IF(AND(B1>=0.01,B1<=5.99),A1*0.2, IF(AND(B1>=6,B1<=11.99),A1*0.5, IF(AND(B1>=12,B1<=23.99),A1*1, A1*1+A1*ROUNDUP((B1-24)/12,0)/2))))

Comment: Thank you Michal, that's brillant.

Answer (score 0):

With the times running down column A, put this formula into column B.

```
=(LOOKUP(A2*24, {0,0.1,6,12}, {0,0.2,0.5,1})+CEILING(MAX(A2-1.5, 0), 0.5))*150
```

Fill down as necessary. I've tried to isolate the $150.00 as much as possible. It should be easy to put that in a cell (e.g. Z1) and reference it instead of hard-coding the amount in (e.g. `...*$Z$1`)

[image: Allowance factor]

Comment: time does not run down, it is in a single cell and changes depending on the figure typed in by a user. The allowance is accumulated. Thank you for your help Jeeped.

Answer (score 0):

**Escalated allocation based on time**

*I’m posting these solutions for the benefit of users that might refer to this question.*

Let’s first validate the criteria provided in the question, *as there some discrepancies between the description of the criteria and the formulas provided priority is given to the formulas as it was confirmed they are correct*.

[image]

Fig. 1

Would like to validate\highlight three points from the table:

i. Minimum allowance rate is 20% as soon as there is time reported *(i.e. `Time > 0`)*

ii. If `Time > 24` hours and `Time < 36` hours the allowance rate is 100%

iii. If `Time >= 48` hours and `Time > 60` hours allowance rate is 200% *(100% first 24 hours + 50% every successive 12 hours)*

Although, when asked

> whether the times to be used as criteria are actual times or integers
>   and mixed numbers representing hours

the user “confirmed” that

> “there are actual times”

It seems that they are not, due to the fact that the user later acknowledges as correct a formula that cannot provide correct results if the time is expressed as *“actual time”*. Figure 2 shows time expressed in both ways.

[image]

Fig. 2

**Solutions**

Below you’ll find formulas to apply for each format.

*Different references as the ones provided in the sample are used in order to allow showing both ways of expressing the `Time` and their solutions. Change the references as required.*

Assuming the Allowance base amount of `150` is located at `C2`

1. Solutions for `Time` expressed as `Double` *(see Fig. 3)*

a. Nested `IF` formula: with the `Time` at `C8` enter this formula in `E8`

```
    =$C$2
    * SUM( IF( $C8 <= 0, 0,
    IF( $C8 < 6, 20%,
    IF( $C8 < 12, 50%, 100% ))),
    MAX( INT( $C8 / 12 ) - 2, 0 ) * 50% )
```

b. Formula based on Jeeped solution: with the `Time` at `C9` enter this formula in `E9`

```
    =$C$2
    * ( LOOKUP( ROUND( $C9, 2 ), {0,0;0.01,0.2;6,0.5;12,1} )
    + CEILING( MAX( ( $C9 / 24 ) - 1.5 + 0.0001, 0 ), 0.5 ))
```

[image]

Fig. 3

2. Solution for `Time` expressed as `Actual Time` *(see Fig. 4)*

*(variation from 1 is that `Time` is multiplied by 24 to convert it as a double)*

a. Nested `IF` formula: With the `Time` at `C13` enter this formula in `E13`

```
    =$C$2
    * SUM( IF( $C13 * 24  <= 0, 0,
    IF( $C13 * 24  < 6, 20%,
    IF( $C13 * 24  < 12, 50%, 100% ))),
    MAX( INT( $C13 * 24  / 12 ) - 2, 0 ) * 50% )
```

b.  Formula based on Jeeped solution: with the `Time` at `C14` enter this formula in `E14`

```
    =$C$2
    * ( LOOKUP( ROUND( $C14 * 24, 2), {0,0;0.01,0.2;6,0.5;12,1})
    + CEILING( MAX( $C14 - 1.5 + 0.0001, 0 ), 0.5 ))
```

[image]

Fig. 4